# Deploy Angular App on IIS Server, reload brings me back to homepage

Tags: angular, iis

I have an issue with my IIS configuration where I cannot make the suburls or redirects work.

When I open my site: localhost/AngularLogin everything looks good, when I press <kbd>f5</kbd> the site still loads and everything is fine

Now when I click the button that has an AngularRoute binding to localhost/AngularLogin/home it loads the site perfectly, but when I press <kbd>f5</kbd> I get redirected to the start URL which is localhost/AngularLogin

Here is some of my Code:

IIS web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/AngularLogin" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

index.html tag

```
 <base href="/AngularLogin/">
```

Angular Routing

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { ModulesComponent } from './modules/modules.component';
import { ConfigurationsComponent } from './configurations/configurations.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'users', pathMatch: 'full', component: UsersComponent },
  { path: 'configs', component: ConfigurationsComponent },
  { path: 'modules', component: ModulesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My Folder Structure looks like this

- AngularLogin (IIS Folder is mapped here)

  - assets
  - index.html
  - web.config
  - main.js

Hope this helps! Thanks in advance

Tried many Solutions I've found on the web, but haven't found a case for mine. IIS is just a pain to use

Comment: could you try this rule:`<rules><rule name="Routes" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/AngularLogin/(.*)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/AngularLogin/index.html" />
                </rule>`

Comment: 1) You only defined a rewrite rule on IIS, not a redirect rule, so whatever redirects your browser cannot be IIS itself. 2) Anything new can be a pain to use. That's why troubleshooting tools like FRT are useful, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Find out what redirects the browser and you can fix it. 3) Use privacy tabs of your web browsers when you test such web apps, because they don't cache previous redirections.

Comment: you can also remove your redirect rules and use hashlocationstrategy: https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy